# pytest fixture with scope session running for every test

Tags: python, pytest

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if a fixture is defined with `scope="session"`, shouldn't it be run only once per the whole `pytest` run?

For example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo(scope="session"):
    print('foooooo')


def test_foo(foo):
    assert False

def test_bar(foo):
    assert False
```

I have some tests that rely on data retrieved from some APIs, and instead of querying the API in each test, I rather have a fixture that gets all the data at once, and then each test uses the data it needs. However, I was noticing that for every test, a request was made to the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're declaring the fixture wrong. `scope` should go into the `pytest.fixture` decoraror parameters:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def foo():
    print('foooooo')
```

In your code, the scope is left to default value `function`, that's why the fixture is being ran for each test.

Comment: beat me to it!! Here's the docs for reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

Comment: Indeed, this was the main issue and the answer to the question. Also, for the record, I found also another issue I had in my code: `pytest.fail` ends the session :)